# ContentProvider: неравильное формирование URI при вызове метода insert()

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, contentprovider

Хочу добавить новую запись в БД `SQLITE`, используя `ContentProvider`.
Возникает ошибка:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.sampleapp, PID: 7831
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Invalid Insert URI: content://com.example.sampleapp.data/inbox
```

Причину (но не первопричину) я понял: как Вы видите, в URI отсутсвует номер строки из БД.

Сохранение осуществляю следующим образом:

```
private void saveItem() {

    Date currentUnixstamp = new Date();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put(Inbox.COLUMN_TITLE, title);
    contentValues.put(Inbox.COLUMN_CONTENT, noteText.toString());

    Uri newItemUri;

    if (newItem){
        contentValues.put(Inbox.COLUMN_CREATED, currentUnixstamp.toString());
        contentValues.put(Inbox.COLUMN_UPDATED, "");
        newItemUri = getContentResolver().insert(Inbox.CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
        finish();
    }
```

Метод insert из наследника `ContentProvider` (работает в другом приложении, так что скорее всего, причина не здесь):

```
@Nullable
@Override
public Uri insert(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable ContentValues contentValues) {

    Uri newInboxItemUri;

    switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)){
        case SINGLE_INBOX_ITEM:
            long rowID = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase().insert(Inbox.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
            if (rowID > 0){
                newInboxItemUri = Inbox.buildInboxItemUri(rowID);
                getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
            }
            else{
                throw new SQLException(getContext().getString(R.string.invalidDbRowIdException) + rowID);
            }
            break;
        default:
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException(getContext().getString(R.string.invalidInsertUri_Exception) + uri);
    }

    return newInboxItemUri;
}
```

В манифесте, я думаю всё нормально, потому что иначе вылезла другая ошибка, но на всякий случай приведу код:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    <!-- ... -->
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!-- ... -->

        <provider
            android:name=".data.ThisAppContentProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.sampleapp.data"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false">
        </provider>

</application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению я не вижу значение константы "SINGLE_INBOX_ITEM", но мне кажется, что при инсёрте она отрабатывать не будет. Т.к. обычно такая константа используется при обращении к одной записи с ID, а у Вас ID еще нет, т.к. это вставка. Поэтому код продолжает выполнение в "default:
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException ....". Судя по всему, Вам нужно использовать другой "case" в вашем "switch" в методе "insert(...)".

Comment: Да! Я перепутал константу. У `SINGLE_INBOX_ITEM` значение `1`, а нужна было `ALL_INBOX_ITEMS` со значением `2`. Вот что значит "профессионал". Спасибо Вам за ответ!